# React - Import big JSON file - Memory Error HEAP

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory, heap-memory, allocation

**Error:**
"FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory" error

I have a working react app with a relatively small footprint.
However I want to import a JSON file in my React-App with lots of data.
The file size is 80MB.

I import the file using:
import MYJSON from './myfile.json'

**What I've tested is increasing my memory for the react app to 12GB.**

"node --max-old-space-size=12000 node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start"

How can it be that an 80MB file raise the memory footprint of node from under 4GB to over 12GB with a single 80MB JSON file import and the app didn't start or build?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

80MB should not be a problem, but anyway you can try to open it using `fs` like a normal file and parse it to a Javascript object using `JSON.parse`.

Hope it helps.

Luis.